# Differences between import filename and import directoryname in Python

Tags: python

In Python, when we do `import modulename`, is there any material difference between

- a file `modulename.py`
- a directory with the same contents in `modulename/__init__.py`?

Concretely: consider a file `m.py` containing `s = "hello"`:

```
>>> import m
>>> m.s
'hello'
```

If instead we have a directory `m` with a file `__init__.py` containing the same `s = "hello"`, we get the identical result.

Obviously the value of `__file__` is different during execution, and the directory structure can have submodules.

**Are there any other differences at all?  With any variant of `import` (`from`/`as`/etc) ?**

---

*I'm really only concerned with Python 3, but version-specific details also welcomed for historic interest.*

Comment: In this limited scenario, they are identical. But understanding the broader picture is probably important if you have reason to ask about this. The argument to `import` is neither a "file name" nor a "directory name"; there is a nontrivial conceptual construction around "modules", "packages", and "namespaces".

Comment: @tripleee Thanks for your comment.  I'm using `import filename` as a shorthand for `import modulename` where the finder will find a file called `modulename.py`; symmetric for directoryname.  I'm quite aware of the module, package and namespace concepts and am looking for an answer in those terms.  As far as I can tell, the `dir/__init__.py` method allows for  submodules by adding the `__path__` attribute to the created module object, but I've found nothing else different.

Comment: You are not finding any difference since modules can be constructed by a single file or a folder. In the latter case, each module has a different submodule that can be initialized or imported separatedly. Anyways, if you place an `__init__.py` in a folder, it's meant to be used as a whole module.

Comment: @JoseM.González Thank you for your comment.  My question is really about non-package-module (`m.py`) versus a package (`m/__init__py`) but which has no submodules.